# SFTP dual authentication with batchfile

Tags: linux, sftp, 2-factor-authentication

I'm trying to connect to a server where dual authentication `(publickey,password)` is enabled. I'm using `sshpass` to provide password to automate the script, but when I have batchfile with SFTP, connection fails without batchfile connection succeeds

> ```
> export SSHPASS=helloworld
>
> (sshpass -e sftp -b batfile.txt -o 'PasswordAuthentication=yes' \
>  -o 'PreferredAuthentications=publickey,password' -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' user@hostname)
> ```

Error:

> ```
> Permission denied (password).
> Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
> ```

Connection is successful without batchfile

> ```
> (sshpass -e sftp -o 'PasswordAuthentication=yes' \
>  -o 'PreferredAuthentications=publickey,password' -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' user@hostname)
> ```

I've tried providing password inside a batchfile but no luck.

Is it possible what I'm trying to achieve `sshpass` along with `batchfile`, if so, can someone please help me on this

Batchfile:

```
echo  "Hey, I'm from Inside"  
!echo "Hey, I'm from Outside"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-b` prevents interactive authentication (what you attempt to simulate by `sshpass`).

Instead, you will need to pass the commands to `sshpass` stdin.

```
sshpass -e sftp -o 'PasswordAuthentication=yes' \
 -o 'PreferredAuthentications=publickey,password' user@hostname < batfile.txt
```

Like here:
[How to put sshpass command inside a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19302572/850848#19302674)

---

*Never use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`, unless you do not care about security.*